# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AlbumsController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my web app I'm trying to make a show action in which the current_users photos are showed for a particular album when that album is clicked. However, every time I click on the link to the show action I get an error saying 'Couldn't find Album with 'id'=:id [WHERE "albums"."user_id" = ?]'. The show action looks like this:

```
def show
    @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
    @photos = @album.photos
end
```

view:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="main-background">

    <% @albums.each do |x| %>
            <div class="big-albums"><%= link_to x.name, "/albums/:id", :style => "text-decoration:none;" %></div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="new-album">
        <%= link_to 'New Album', "/albums/new", :style => "text-decoration:none;" %>
        <div class="plus-sign">
            <%= link_to '+', "/albums/new", :style => "text-decoration:none; color:black; font-size:80px; color:#85adad;" %>
        </div>          
    </div>

</div>
```

routes:

```
      get '/albums' => 'albums#index', as: :albums
  get '/albums/new' => 'albums#new'
  post '/albums/new' => 'albums#create'
  get '/albums/:id' => 'albums#show'
  get '/albums/:id/destroy' => 'albums#destroy'
```

Comment: Can you show the view file (name and content) from which you click on the desired album ?

Comment: Just added view and routes @Maxence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the `link_to` URL you're displaying

```
link_to x.name, "/albums/:id"
```

That's assigning `:id` as the argument passed to the URL. Instead you want to do something like `"/albums/#{x.id}"` so that it uses the album ID as the ID parameter on the URL path.

Comment: After trying that I got an error saying 'uninitialized constant Album::Photo' @Leo Correa

Comment: @nums do you have a `Photo` model and an association on `Album` for `has_many :photos`?